# C++ MySQL++ undefined reference to dlclose

Tags: c++, ubuntu, gcc, mysql++

So I get this error when compiling a program with mysql++ under Ubuntu 12.04 LTS x64 with GCC. In detail its:

```
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.a(client_plugin.c.o): In function add_plugin:
(.text+0x253): undefined reference to dlclose
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.a(client_plugin.c.o): In function mysql_client_plugin_deinit:
(.text+0x2c7): undefined reference to dlclose
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.a(client_plugin.c.o): In function mysql_load_plugin_v:
(.text+0x524): undefined reference to dlopen
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.a(client_plugin.c.o): In function mysql_load_plugin_v:
(.text+0x54a): undefined reference to dlsym
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.a(client_plugin.c.o): In function mysql_load_plugin_v:
(.text+0x67f): undefined reference to dlerror
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.a(client_plugin.c.o): In function mysql_load_plugin_v:
(.text+0x695): undefined reference to dlclose
```

I have installed: libmysql++-3, libmysqlclient18 and libmysqlclient18-dev, libdml3 and libdml3-dev 
Libraries are linked in the following order:

```
/usr/lib/libmysqlpp.a
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.a
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.a
```

And as linker include directories I have:

```
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
```

Comment: Sounds like you should `-ldl` only after `-lmysqlclient`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making the comment into an answer. so that it doesn't get lost:

You have to link `-ldl` only after `-lmysqlclient`. The link order matters.

Comment: This was helpful when I got the same error in a completely unrelated project. And I don't know what I'm doing, I moved `dl` after what I guessed was the dependent object and it solved my problem! Thank you.